# Addthis Facebook description and title

Tags: facebook, addthis

I've added a Addthis script to my Facebook page tab;

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"
addthis:title="MY TITLE"
    addthis:description="MY TITLE"> 
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=XXXX">    </script>
```

I've also added the correct Title and description to the Page in my Facebook Tab but when I share, I don't get the correct Title and Description. Instead I get the default from my Facebook homepage?

Answer (score 0):

As Paul points out in the second answer of [this thread](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/266403-custom-title-description-not-working-for-facebook-share-link-), facebook share links of addThis don´t work with the normal addThis parameters.
You have to add the required facebook meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title here" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="your description here" />
```

to your page.
You can find further tags at the facebook open graph documentation
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/