# Set Facebook share title and description dynamically using addthis

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share, addthis

addthis widget doesn't seem to integrate well with Facebook when it comes to customizing its share message.

When I try to set title and description via addthis.update, i.e:

```
addthis.update('share', 'description', "Content to be shared" );
```

Everything works perfectly with Twitter, but Facebook is a no show, neither the template nor description/ title are being set. Using addthis:description inline attributes doesn't work either.

Also tried using meta tags without success, as suggested on [Addthis Facebook description and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042030/addthis-facebook-description-and-title)

Did anyone manage to sucessfully customize sharing with Facebook?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page where it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < addthis.links.length; i++){
   addthis.links[i].share.description = "new description";
}
```

That's raw access to addthis share objects properties.